# Averages Per Hour Per Day Over Set Time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the average number of calls, per hour, per day of the week, over a variable time line. So far, I have been able to parse out the incoming calls and assign a day of the week to them. Here is a snippet of the table I am working off of:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| day  | H1   | H2   | H3   | H4   |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| Tue  |    1 |    1 |    3 |    5 |
| Wed  |    3 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
| Thu  |    0 |    3 |    0 |    5 |
| Fri  |    3 |    2 |    4 |   11 |
| Sat  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| Sun  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    2 |
| Mon  |    1 |    2 |    2 |    8 |
| Tue  |    1 |    1 |    2 |    6 |
| Wed  |    1 |    1 |    4 |    3 |
| Thu  |    0 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
| Fri  |    0 |    3 |    3 |    6 |
| Sat  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    4 |
| Sun  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Mon  |    1 |    2 |    2 |    8 |
| Tue  |    1 |    4 |    2 |    7 |
| Wed  |    1 |    3 |    2 |    6 |
| Thu  |    1 |    1 |    2 |    6 |
```

I am having a hard time trying to figure out a way to total up each hourly column by the day, and then average them out.

The end result should be something like

```
Day  H1   H2   H3   H4
Tue  1    2    2.33 6
Wed  1.66 2    3    4.33
Thu  0.33 1.66 1.33 4.66
```

Each column added up per day, and then divided by 3, the number of instances of that day. Keep in mind, the number of instances of each day will change, such as Monday and Friday only showing up twice on the table.

I've been trying to figure out a clean way of doing this, but I am also having a hard time figuring out how to even get the count of each day over the given time frame.

Please and thank you!
DW

Comment: Your best bet is to turn the table into name/value pairs and then (so the table looks like day/hours for each day/column (H1, H2, etc).  The base table is poorly formed to do this analysis.  The solution is to break them down into these kinds of pairs in a temp table and perform the query against that temporary table.  Sorry - first sentence was written before one of my boxes decided to eat a disk.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
What would that query look like? I am having a hard time picturing what you're suggesting. How I would implement the averaging out over time function to it? The snippet of the table I have is something that I made off a feed we get from our phone provider, I should be able to put it in a different format if that is the only way forward.
Thank you again.

Comment: This is a pretty simple way to do it.  I've done it in the past using information_schema.columns, but unless you really want to know how the dictionary works, I'd try this:  http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,day  CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,H INT NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (day,h,val) VALUES
('Tue' , 1 ,  1),
('Wed' , 1 ,  3),
('Thu' , 1 ,  0),
('Fri' , 1 ,  3),
('Sat' , 1 ,  0),
('Sun' , 1 ,  0),
('Mon' , 1 ,  1),
('Tue' , 1 ,  1),
('Wed' , 1 ,  1),
('Thu' , 1 ,  0),
('Fri' , 1 ,  0),
('Sat' , 1 ,  0),
('Sun' , 1 ,  0),
('Mon' , 1 ,  1),
('Tue' , 1 ,  1),
('Wed' , 1 ,  1),
('Thu' , 1 ,  1),
('Tue' , 2 ,  1),
('Wed' , 2 ,  2),
('Thu' , 2 ,  3),
('Fri' , 2 ,  2),
('Sat' , 2 ,  0),
('Sun' , 2 ,  0),
('Mon' , 2 ,  2),
('Tue' , 2 ,  1),
('Wed' , 2 ,  1),
('Thu' , 2 ,  1),
('Fri' , 2 ,  3),
('Sat' , 2 ,  0),
('Sun' , 2 ,  0),
('Mon' , 2 ,  2),
('Tue' , 2 ,  4),
('Wed' , 2 ,  3),
('Thu' , 2 ,  1),
('Tue' , 3 ,  3),
('Wed' , 3 ,  3),
('Thu' , 3 ,  0),
('Fri' , 3 ,  4),
('Sat' , 3 ,  0),
('Sun' , 3 ,  0),
('Mon' , 3 ,  2),
('Tue' , 3 ,  2),
('Wed' , 3 ,  4),
('Thu' , 3 ,  2),
('Fri' , 3 ,  3),
('Sat' , 3 ,  0),
('Sun' , 3 ,  0),
('Mon' , 3 ,  2),
('Tue' , 3 ,  2),
('Wed' , 3 ,  2),
('Thu' , 3 ,  2),
('Tue' , 4 ,  5),
('Wed' , 4 ,  4),
('Thu' , 4 ,  5),
('Fri' , 4 , 11),
('Sat' , 4 ,  1),
('Sun' , 4 ,  2),
('Mon' , 4 ,  8),
('Tue' , 4 ,  6),
('Wed' , 4 ,  3),
('Thu' , 4 ,  3),
('Fri' , 4 ,  6),
('Sat' , 4 ,  4),
('Sun' , 4 ,  0),
('Mon' , 4 ,  8),
('Tue' , 4 ,  7),
('Wed' , 4 ,  6),
('Thu' , 4 ,  6);

SELECT day,h,AVG(val)x FROM my_table GROUP BY day,h;
+-----+---+--------+
| day | h | x      |
+-----+---+--------+
| Fri | 1 | 1.5000 |
| Fri | 2 | 2.5000 |
| Fri | 3 | 3.5000 |
| Fri | 4 | 8.5000 |
| Mon | 1 | 1.0000 |
| Mon | 2 | 2.0000 |
| Mon | 3 | 2.0000 |
| Mon | 4 | 8.0000 |
| Sat | 1 | 0.0000 |
| Sat | 2 | 0.0000 |
| Sat | 3 | 0.0000 |
| Sat | 4 | 2.5000 |
| Sun | 1 | 0.0000 |
| Sun | 2 | 0.0000 |
| Sun | 3 | 0.0000 |
| Sun | 4 | 1.0000 |
| Thu | 1 | 0.3333 |
| Thu | 2 | 1.6667 |
| Thu | 3 | 1.3333 |
| Thu | 4 | 4.6667 |
| Tue | 1 | 1.0000 |
| Tue | 2 | 2.0000 |
| Tue | 3 | 2.3333 |
| Tue | 4 | 6.0000 |
| Wed | 1 | 1.6667 |
| Wed | 2 | 2.0000 |
| Wed | 3 | 3.0000 |
| Wed | 4 | 4.3333 |
+-----+---+--------+
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that this will be a report that is used over months worth of data, with over 30 columns for each day of the month. Inputing each bit of data would be impractical at best. Thank you for the suggestions though.

Comment: Your idea of what is and isn't practical is entirely wrongheaded. 30/31 columns is a daft strategy

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am trying to build a query that takes into account months to years worth of data, it seems rather time consuming to manually input each bit of information. The columns are in half hour increments over the course of a work day. Not sure what you mean by "daft" but thank you for the feed back.

Comment: Relational databases rely on normalised design, such as I have provided. While you're not obliged to use my design, I would suggest you employ something quite similar, or otherwise dispense with the idea of using an RDBMS in resolution of this problem.

Comment: Most of that has gone right over my head, I am very much a novice at MySQL and CS in general. I will continue to work this out, and keep your design in mind moving forward. Thank you again.